# Combine 2 paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, asset-pipeline, nested-routes

I'm new to rails and i'm sure this is a simple question but I haven't been able to find it. I have a `product` model and a `sku` model. A product `has_many` skus. I have a route setup to use a path like this: `/products/1/skus/3`

What I'm trying to figure out is how to link to different skus from this view using a `link_to` method. e.g.: `= link_to @product_path + @sku_path` and have it come out to be `<a href="/products/1/skus/2">`

`@product` and `@sku` are variables from the controller.

I know I could use a join and pass in the id's etc. But I wasn't sure if there was a better way of doing it. Maybe use a helper?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give that you have

```
#routes.rb
resources :products do
  resources :skus
end
```

you should be able to do

```
product_sku_path(@product, @sku)
```

to get a given sku associated with a product, good luck :)